# Add Captcha Image to laravel App without installing any package

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, captcha

I already uploaded a laravel app and my boss wants me to add a captcha image to the website, now I researched a lot of captcha techniques for laravel and it all requires me to install a package, the problem is I dont want to reupload the website. Any solutions on this?

Comment: Well you will have to re-upload some files anyways. Doesn't matter if you add a package or just add some code anywhere else...

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do, you're going to need to write code and upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there exists a way using php library in laravel without using composer http://www.onlinekurukshetra.com/using-captcha-in-laravel-without-composer/ works fine for me.

Also custom validation using laravel for validating the captcha is there. But Need a way validate it client side. Think you have to made custom code for it.